# Using Batch file and VBS to change an IP

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have equipment that comes with a default ip address that I need to change via telnet.
The new ip will always be the same except for the last two octets.
I currently access the equipment with a batch file that call on a .vbs

```
@ECHO OFF
:: Get Hub IP
set /p input1="Enter Hub and press ENTER  "
set /p input2="Enter Shelf and press ENTER  "
@ECHO OFF
::Run script to Set IP Address
start telnet.exe 10.230.%input1%.%input2%
cscript SetIPAddress.vbs  .
echo "DONE!"
pause
```

HERE IS THE VBS

```
set OBJECT=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.sleep 1000 
OBJECT.SendKeys "admin{ENTER}" 
WScript.sleep 1000 
OBJECT.SendKeys "admin{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 1000 
OBJECT.SendKeys "configure{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 2000
```

This works fine
What I need is to add something like this

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /p paramA=Hub: 
SET /p paramB=Shelf:
ECHO set interfaces eth0 10.230.%paramA%.254 mask 255.255.255.0 gateway 10.230.%paramA%.254
PAUSE
```

This also works fine but I’m not sure how to get it to send to the command prompt.
Can it be added to the .vbs or can the elements of the .vbs be added to the batch file?

Comment: Why not send the command(s) as text via SendKeys()?

Comment: where the %paraA% is i need user input as that will always change

Comment: You could perhaps use VBScript to do that: http://ss64.com/vb/stdoutread.html

Comment: maybe but this is only my 2nd day working with vbs and batch files so i have no clus as to how to add it. sorry

Comment: Put that `set interfaces eth0...` command into a variable and add it to the `cscript` command in place of that pointless period you have there.  `cscript /nologo SetIPAddress.vbs "%cmdToRun%"`.  Then in your VBScript, `OBJECT.SendKeys WSH.Arguments(0) & "~"`.  (By the way, `"~"` is the same thing as `"{ENTER}"` with `SendKeys`.)